# Argument type 'void' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Action'

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

This is my test code:

```
class PassingInActionStatement
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dsufac = new DoSomethingUsefulForAChange();

        dsufac.Do(WriteToConsole);
        dsufac.Do2(s => WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test"));
        dsufac.Do(WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test")); // Does not compile
    }

    internal static void WriteToConsole()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    internal static void WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra(String input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}

internal class DoSomethingUsefulForAChange
{
    internal void Do(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }

    internal void Do2(Action<String> action)
    {
        action("");
    }
}
```

The first 2 calls work but I am wondering why the 3rd one does not. I do not fancy the code inside Do2 as it seems strange that I have type type `action("")` in there in order to get it to work.

Could someone please explain the 2 things I do not understand please?

1. Why I can not write the third line like that with calling Do
2. Why I have to write action("") in order get it to work in Do2

Comment: I always marked replies that helped me out. If there is not a solution that provides something useful I do not mark it until I get the answer that helps me out.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
dsufac.Do(WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test"));
```

actually calls the function first (`WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test")`) and then attempts to pass the result into `Do`. Since there is no result (`void`), it's not possible.

What you actually want is this:

```
dsufac.Do(() => WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test"));
```

The inner part *declares* a function that takes nothing (the `() =>` bit), which calls `WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test")` when executed. *Then* your `dsufac.Do` call will receive an action, like it expects.

As for `Do2` - you've declared it as taking `Action<String>`, which means that `action` is a function that **takes one argument**. You have to pass it a string. That string might be empty, like in your `action("")` example, or it might be passed in externally, as in something like this:

```
dsufac.Do3(WriteToConsole, "Test");

...

internal void Do3(Action<String> action, String str)
{
    action(str);
}
```

Comment: Waw! That works. I am still having lots of problems with that Action and Func stuff. Are there some decent tutorials besides MSDN or books you can suggest? I will mark your answer as such when it allowes me to (apparently have to wait for another ... minutes).

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
dsufac.Do(WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test"));
```

is interpreted like the following

```
var variable = WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test");
dsufac.Do(variable);
```

As the return type of WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test") is void, so you can not actually pass it to dsufac.Do(). That is why its not getting compiled. But for the first one

```
dsufac.Do(WriteToConsole);
```

you are not calling the function, rather you are passing it as a method group, which is later get invoked in the Do() method of dsufac object. But if you want to write the 3rd line as the 1st one, you can use

```
dsufac.Do(() => WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra("Test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do expects an `Action` (i.e. method which take no parameters and returns no value). Hence `WriteToConsoleWithSomethingExtra` is not a valid fit - takes one string parameter.
2. Do2 accepts an `Action<T>` (i.e. method which takes in one T parameter and returns no value). Hence when you invoke the delegate/action you need to supply one parameter of type T, here String.