# Function as parameter (Without return result type)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm trying to pass a method as a parameter. The method does not return anything (void) so I do it in the form of `Action`. The error occurs when I invoke `Execute` from the commands. This is the error:

> Can not be converted from '`void`' to '`System.Action`'.

Any help?

```
private async void Execute(Action runAction)
{
    ...

    await TaskEx.Run(() => runAction);

    ...

}

_command1 = new RelayCommand(Execute(Class.ExecuteVoidMethod1()), () => CanExecuteVoidMethod1());
```

**EDIT**

```
_command1 = new RelayCommand(Execute(() => Class.ExecuteVoidMethod1()), () => CanExecuteVoidMethod1()); // Same Error

_command1 = new RelayCommand(Execute(() => Class.ExecuteVoidMethod1), () => CanExecuteVoidMethod1()); // Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await expresion and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Hi and thanks, but Func is used when you need a return value? It is not like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument type 'void' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Action'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387812/argument-type-void-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-type-system-action)

Comment: You need to use `TaskEx.Run(() => runAction())` or just `TaskEx.Run(runAction)`. At the moment you are passing a `Func<Action>`.

Comment: no :( i try with "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387812/argument-type-void-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-type-system-action" and have the same error. Go to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call your action in the `Execute` method?

```
await TaskEx.Run(() => runAction);
```

You must run it like this:

```
await TaskEx.Run(() => runAction());
```

In other case you are returning your action instead of running it.